# QMake / jom force extra MIDL compiler to run before RC

Tags: qmake, rc, midl, parallel-builds

I'm converting an old OCX project to QMake (as it's getting the "new" standard in my company).
In my Button.pro file, I add the MIDL compiler by the means of

```
idl_c.output = $${DESTDIR}/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.tlb
idl_c.input = IDL
idl_c.commands = $${QMAKE_IDL} ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} $${IDLFLAGS} \
                 /tlb ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
idl_c.variable_out = GENERATED_FILES
idl_c.CONFIG += target_predeps
idl_c.name = MIDL

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += idl_c

IDL += $$PWD/Button.odl
```

The .pro file also mentions that I have a RC file

```
RC_FILE += $$PWD/Button.rc
```

This RC file contains a TYPELIB for this tlb file, meaning that it has to be available **before** rc.exe runs

```
1 TYPELIB "Button.tlb"
```

I then generate a makefile through QMake and build my project using nmake. Everything runs fine: the console shows no error and the output OCX is generated (and works). I can clearly see that MIDL is executed first, the RC, then the rest.
If I try to build using jom, the order is not satisfied anymore. jom seems to try to execute MIDL and RC in parallel: Button.tlb is then not yet existing at the time RC.exe needs it and the build fails.

Is there a way to force jom to wait for midl to be done before starting rc?

I'm using QT 5.3.1 under MSVC2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMake is nothing more than a makefile generator. And your issue is due to make (or jom) parallel job execution. To fix this you only have to induce a single dependency (w/o any recipe) in a Makefile between `res/obj` and `tlb` files. This could be done with:

```
dep_restlb.target = $(RES_FILE)
dep_restlb.depends = $${DESTDIR}/Button.tlb # QMAKE_FILE_BASE is not available here
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += dep_restlb
```

Comment: I must admit I couldn't expect it to be so simple...
${RES_FIL} doesn't exist, so I had to modify it the following way:
```
dep_restlb.target = $$OBJECTS_DIR\Button.res
dep_restlb.depends = $${DESTDIR}/Button.tlb
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += dep_restlb
```

... and it did the trick!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NonoxX `${RES_FILE}` will be defined in Makefile. Thus a single dollar.

Comment: It definately isn't
```
Error: Invalid macro invocation found in E:\Projects\Button\Makefile line 463
```

Comment: @NonoxX Strange, I was sure it is defined for nmake too. Okay, then it's specific to gcc generator only.

Comment: I think I found  out: ${RES_FILE} doesn't exist. $(RES_FILE) does :)
Still have to get rid of it in the distclean, as for soe reason it doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: @NonoxX Ah, so nmake/jom simply does not  like POSIX syntax.